# Doesn't work the method .attr(). JS. What's the problem?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know why, but in this case "attr" doesn't work. I've connected jQuery so that's not the problem.

I think the problem has to do with that we get the div not with $(""). Because if I use divs.attr(..) it works.

```js
$(function(){
    let divs = $("div");
    for (let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        const div = divs[i];
        
        div.attr("class", "red");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you explain what are trying to do? Add class red to all divs or get all divs with attribute red?

Comment: This most certainly is a duplicate to a question somewhere here on SO. With `divs[i]` you get an `HTMLElement` out of the jQuery result set. `attr()` is however function of a jQuery results set. So you either have to write `$(div).attr(`, (`$(div)` creates a jQuery result set containing the element `div`) or use the [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) of the DOM API.

Comment: You answered yourself in your question. Inside the loop wrap `div` in jQuery object to call jQeury `attr()` method on it like this:  `$(div).attr("class", "red");`

Comment: why are you use attr to set a class?

Comment: There is an [`addClass` method](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/).

Comment: `const div = divs.eq(i);` to keep jquery objects rather than keep switching in and out of jquery/DOM

Comment: **Always check the browser console for errors** - in this case the browser is kind enough to tell you that `div.attr is not a function`